# How to compare previous and updated props Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am getting an array from props, and i should trigger a function when the length of an array is changed. Due to the docs, i should use the following construction "handler: function (val, oldVal)", but it returns the new length.

```
props: ['array']
watch: {
  array: function(val, oldVal) { // watch it
    console.log('Prop changed: ', val, ' | was: ', oldVal) // it always returns the new array 
  }
}
```

Maybe i should use some of the lifecycle hooks?

Answer (score 1):

Most of JavaScript's built-in array functionality mutates an array rather than creating a new array. Vue will detect the changes but the underlying behaviour remains the same, the array is modified.

For example, `array.push(17)` adds a new value to the end of the same array, it does not create a new array.

If you modify an array it will notify the `watch` function but the 'new' array is just the same object as the original array. So Vue **is** passing you the old array, you've just modified that array. Vue does not store a copy of the original state of that array.

From [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch):

> Note: when mutating (rather than replacing) an Object or an Array, the old value will be the same as new value because they reference the same Object/Array. Vue doesn’t keep a copy of the pre-mutate value.

If you just care about the length you could do something like this:

```
computed: {
    arrayLength () {
        return this.array.length
    }
},

watch: {
    arrayLength (newLength, oldLength) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

or more directly:

```
watch: {
    'array.length' (newLength, oldLength) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you really need the old array then you'll either have to pass in a copy as the prop value, or take a copy within your component.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code sample. Below is a working example.

- Are you sure the array you are passing as a prop is changing?
- Are you sure you are correctly mutating the array?

Check out [Vuejs Docs - Array Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

```js
    Vue.component('child', {
        template: '<div>Array length is {{ array.length }}</div>',
        props: {
            array: {
                type: Array,
                default: () => [],
            },
        },
        watch: {
            array: function(val, oldVal) {
                alert(`changed from ${oldVal.length} to ${val.length}`);
            },
        },
    });

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data() {
            return {
                arr: [1, 2, 3],
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            setTimeout(this.updateArr, 3000);
        },
        methods: {
            updateArr() {
                this.arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
            },
        },
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child :array="arr"></child>
</div>
```